# VB.NET Scheduled Task

Tags: vb.net, scheduled-tasks

I have a VB.NET program, which is used by many windows scheduled tasks and is parameter driven.  Therefore there could be five applicationname.exe processes running at the same time.

I have had problems with some of the scheduled tasks "hanging" recently.  I know the cause of this. However, there is some odd behaviour that I cannot explain.  When the process running the faulty scheduled task hangs none of the others will run (the scheduled task says running in Windows Schedule Tasks but seems to hang as well).  However, after stopping the scheduled task (when a hang occurs) none of the other scheduled tasks will run properly for approximately ten minutes and then everything resumes.

Why do all the scheduled tasks hang when there is only a problem with one? If this question is too vague then I will post some specific code.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Task triggering tools such as Quartz(http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) which has good support for .net applications. They allow you to schedule/ trigger jobs using a timer like syntax.

I understand that this is not a direct answer for your query, but thought it might help someone looking for a scheduled tasks based solution.

Answer (score 0):

What is the cause of the hang?

What is reported in the Windows Event log for a) the hanged application b) the task failing to launch?

You might want to try [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see additional info on the hanging process (maybe shared access to a locked resource?